# Using a VPS for applications and another one for DNS manage: email trouble

Tags: email, dns, system, centos, vps

I've setup on my VPS ISPConfig with success (following the official guide to install ispconfig on centos6).
I use another server/provider to manage domain & dns. On their dns controlpanel I've

```
    *   A   193.200.241.75  0   

    mail    A   193.200.241.75  0   

    manage  A   193.200.241.75  0   

    mx1 A   193.200.241.75  0   

    pop3    A   193.200.241.75  0   

    smtp    A   193.200.241.75  0   

    www A   168.144.196.107 0   

    www2    A   193.200.241.75  0   

    www3    A   193.200.241.75  0   

    mail    MX  193.200.241.75  10  

    mx1 MX  193.200.241.75  10
```

Than on my VPS server (193.200.241.75) I created domain and configured email addresses,
but when I try to test the address (with my personal account) sending an email to info@mydomain.it
I obtain

```
    Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
        info@mydomain.it
    Technical details of permanent failure:
    DNS Error: Domain name not found
```

What's the matter?
Vito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your mx records are wrong. looks like you create mx records for  subdomains mail.domain.it and mx1.domain.it instead for domain.it itself and they point to an ip address instead of a hostname. also you seem to try to configure two mx records to the same host

=>

remove

> mail    MX  193.200.241.75  10
>
> mx1 MX  193.200.241.75  10

replace with

>

> MX mail 10

(not 100% sure about the format for the line.. ist this a bind style zonefile?
if you have a hostname field a gui, just leave it empty. it's also possitble that you have to fully qualify mail.domain.it. instead of just mail.  depends on your type of dns setup.
)

Comment: thank's but take a look to my post. I have already set the value you suggest.

Comment: ah, sorry, you actually did create the A record as well.. my mistake. still, your MX records should point to the A record, not the IP. and the content should be the domain itself, not a subdomain